# Map reduce java fails at mapping during its first reading

Tags: java, dictionary, reduce

When I'm trying to debug my program on a simple input, it fails at the `context.write(text, text)` command.  Why is this, and how can I fix it?

```
public class TaskMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
    private Text country = new Text();
    private Text browser = new Text();
    public void map(LongWritable offset, Text line, Context context)

            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] words = line.toString().split(" ");

        country.set(words[1]);
        browser.set(words[0]);

        context.write(country, browser);
    }
}
```

The input file is:

```
Chrome Israel
IE Israel
Firefox Denmark
Safari Denmark
Chrome Israel
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:836)
 at Driver.main(Driver.java:46)

I tried to print when i'm in the map function and it prints only once and then it fails with that exception 836